# Not seeing improvement in response times after using Cloudflare CDN

Tags: php, apache, cdn, cloudflare

I have a php, Mysql, Apache based website. Hosting server located in London.

Opened cloudflare account, enabled and configured my website to route via cloudflare and enabled caching for static content.

Ran a page load test from different countries. and could not see any improvements.

The test tool howwver detects that i am making effective use of CDN. but there isnt any performance improvement.

1 My static resources each takes around 20ms to download when accessed from london.
2. When accessed from other countries, these resources are taking a good 600ms roughly.

am i missing something?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but if your static resource is not in [this list](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) maybe you need to [configure it yourself](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172256-How-do-I-cache-static-HTML-)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

- Are you sending appropriate Cache-Control headers for the static content and confirmed that CloudFlare is caching the content (you should get "HIT" for one of the headers)
- Have you run multiple tests for the resources? Perhaps they just haven't been cached yet so you were getting the timing of the CloudFlare->origin fetch

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare by default does not cache pages, only resources. That may be why your pages are not any faster. If you want your *pages* to be cached and faster, you have to set up rules to do so.